# Show/Save custom fields in Outlook calendar shared from SharePoint calendar

Tags: windows-vista, microsoft-outlook-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Is it possible to create a custom field in a SharePoint calendar, and configure Outlook so that when creating a new appointment, users who have linked that calendar to their Outlook will see and be able to save their entry for that field?

I just want to add a few basic controls, or even a single line field would work, I just want the 6-13 users to be able to manage things from inside Outlook, since they tend to be used to using it, and it tends to run smoother than the web interface for SharePoint.

Comment: Found this on SO:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/945722/adding-shared-fields-to-a-sharepoint-calendar-to-sync-with-an-outlook-calendar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible with the out of box SharePoint and Outlook functionality. We have been working on an Outlook add-in to expose custom columns on SharePoint lists within Outlook. The add-in is called ProperSync and you can find more information at www.propersync.com.

*Disclaimer - I am part of the ProperSync team and hope this is a relevant and helpful posting